# Exported boolean not reactive?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

This has always worked for me but for some reason isn't working now, and feel like I'm just missing something plainly obvious.

I have two files, one connected to a WebSocket, it exports a boolean `connected` initially set to false, which is set to true once the connection is established. The other file is importing the boolean, using it in its view.

However, when the WebSocket connects, the value in the view is not updated. If I switch pages and return, the correct `true` value is shown, but not on the initial load of the page (eg. the page was loaded before the connect happens).

A basic example of the issue is here:
https://svelte.dev/repl/6b6eee6181fb4f848f98c7f261558bb6?version=3.51.0

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import { connected } from "./lib.svelte";
</script>

<h1>
    Connection status [{connected}]
</h1>
```

lib.svelte

```
<script context="module">
export let connected = false;

setTimeout(() => {
  connected = true;
  console.log('fired ' + connected);
}, 4000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) or pass values though props if they are not declared locally and you want them to be reactive. This has never been any different to my knowledge.

In general, when importing from a script, use a store.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, like I mention - if I navigate to a different page in the app and return to the same page, the correct value of `connected` is displayed. So it's getting the right value just not catching the update. I had this working without a store yesterday and today made a number of changes and it seems to have broken.

Comment: That is **not** reactivity, that is probably just the component being destroyed and recreated.

Comment: So, if you have a library in `src/lib` which exports a boolean, and is imported by several components, none of those components get updates? This is confusing because, as I understood it, it was exactly how it had been working for me up until now.

Comment: At any rate, thanks for the answer - it works. I am just baffled at the moment as to how it was working before. :)